# Xamarin.Forms jamesmontemagno settings plugin

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am building xamarin forms app, I am using `jamesmontemagno` settings plugin and I'm adding a property which list of a class. But the thing is I'm not able to add or insert to the list, every time I use method Add or Insert it jump into the get not the set and I can't understand why.

here is my code and thanks for the help in advance:

//adding an item to the list

```
 private void order(Sales_Order_Items sale)
{
    orderlist.Add(sale);
    Settings.Usercartlist.Add(sale);
}
```

I can only set it by using this code

```
Settings.Usercarlist=orderlist;
```

the property in the settings file

```
public static List<Sales_Order_Items> Usercartlist
{
    set
    {
        string listValue = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
        AppSettings.AddOrUpdateValue(myIntListKey, listValue);          
    }
    get
    {
        string value = AppSettings.GetValueOrDefault(myIntListKey, string.Empty);
        List<Sales_Order_Items> myList;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            myList = new List<Sales_Order_Items>();
        else
            myList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Sales_Order_Items>>(value);
        return myList;
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using like the following way you can try that
Ex.

```
 private static UserDetails _currentUser = null;
 public static UserDetails CurrentUser
 {
    get
    {
       if (_currentUser == null)
       {
         string data = AppSettings.GetValueOrDefault(nameof(CurrentUser), string.Empty);
         if (data != null)
            _currentUser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginResponse>(data);
       }
       return _currentUser;
    }

    set
    {
        string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
        AppSettings.AddOrUpdateValue(nameof(CurrentUser), data);
        _currentUser = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When adding an item, the actual object reference does not change. Only the value changes. This is not picked up by the getter or setter.

The only way to update after each item is to add the line you already have: `Settings.Usercarlist=orderlist;` after each operation.